# How do I handle file changes on an electron app (markdown editor)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, vue.js, electron

As a learning excercise I'm trying to implement a simple markdown editor, and was wondering which was the best way to handle changes (made by another app) on the currently open file. Currently I'm watching the file for changes (with nodes "fs" module) and notifying the renderer process of the change to act accordingly (showing a dialog, updating the view, etc), but whenever my own app makes a change (e.g. pressing "save") the event triggers too. Is there a way to know that the event was triggered by my own app and ignore it?

Comment: Not responding to the question but this could be a workaround: you could watch for the file change like you do, and check if the file has been really updated (check if the content is the same as what you have in your app or not), and then refresh the view only if it is different?

Comment: Nice! didn't thought of that, the kind of similar thing I was about to do is keeping track of the time when my app made a change on a file (via the fs.stats info) and if a "change" event arrives and the file still has the same "last change" metadata then i just ignore it. Will try both approaches, huge thanks!